# Polymorphism with servlet session attribute

Tags: java, servlets, polymorphism, session-variables

I'm trying to use polymorphism to simplify working with objects that I store in the servlet session, and I keep getting ClassCastExceptions. I'm using the Struts framework (1.3.10 and Struts 2)

I've got the following:

```
class A{
 // fields omitted
  A{ // initialize}
  load{ //- no implementation }

  // getters + setters
}

class B extends A{
  // fields omitted
  B { // initialize }
  @Override
  load{ // specific implementation}
}

class C extends A{
  // fields omitted
  C { // initialize }
  @Override
  load{ // specific implementation}
}
```

Now, I instantiate as follows, manipulate and store in the session.

```
A obj = new B();
//-- manipulate and load fields here
request.getSession().setAttribute("obj", obj);
```

Later, I want retrieve this object.

```
A laterObject = (A) request.getSession().getAttribute("obj");
//fails to give me B's load() implementation. Same issue for C's load() implementation.
```

I also tried

```
A laterObject = (B) request.getSession().getAttribute("obj");
// ClassCastException
```

My question: is there a way to retrieve EITHER (B) or (C) and run each load method that is specifically implemented for each object? What I want to do is to make my code apply to either B or C using polymorphism, but something seems to get screwed up in the casting (and least I think that's the problem). Maybe there is another way? Maybe my casting is screwed up?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *fails to give me B's load() implementation*? Does it throw an exception? Does it not compile? Does it compile but you can't access methods from `B`?

Comment: May be you ask something that people can understand.

Comment: See below... mea culpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obj is of class A

So first your casting Obj which is A to an A so that is why you get As methods

The second time you are casting a superclass which is A to a subclass B. A doesn't know about B

Comment: Well, this is a "duh" moment, isn't it?  This is what I get for staying up late and working on stuff I want to work on.  thanks...